# Difference between CString::GetbufferSetLength and CString::GetBuffer

Tags: c++, mfc

I wonder what exactly the difference is between [`GetbufferSetLength(some_size)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl-mfc-shared/reference/csimplestringt-class?view=msvc-170&devlangs=cpp&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(ATLSIMPSTR%252FATL%253A%253ACSimpleStringT%253A%253AGetBufferSetLength)%3Bk(CSTRINGT%252FATL%253A%253ACStringT%253A%253AGetBufferSetLength)%3Bk(ATL%253A%253ACSimpleStringT%253A%253AGetBufferSetLength)%3Bk(ATL%253A%253ACStringT%253A%253AGetBufferSetLength)%3Bk(GetBufferSetLength)%3Bk(DevLang-C%252B%252B)%3Bk(TargetOS-Windows)%26rd%3Dtrue#getbuffersetlength) and [`GetBuffer(some_size)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl-mfc-shared/reference/csimplestringt-class?view=msvc-170&devlangs=cpp&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(ATLSIMPSTR%252FATL%253A%253ACSimpleStringT%253A%253AGetBufferSetLength)%3Bk(CSTRINGT%252FATL%253A%253ACStringT%253A%253AGetBufferSetLength)%3Bk(ATL%253A%253ACSimpleStringT%253A%253AGetBufferSetLength)%3Bk(ATL%253A%253ACStringT%253A%253AGetBufferSetLength)%3Bk(GetBufferSetLength)%3Bk(DevLang-C%252B%252B)%3Bk(TargetOS-Windows)%26rd%3Dtrue#getbuffer).

The documentation isn't very clear to me and to me it sounds pretty much both functions do more or less the same thing.

This is my use case:

```
CStringA foo;
char *p = foo.GetBufferSetLength(somelength);

// fill the buffer p with exactly somelength (non null) chars
FillCharBufferWithStuff(p, somelength);

foo.ReleaseBuffer(somelength);  // or should I rather use 
                                // ReleaseBufferSetLength(somelength) ?

// now foo contains the somelength characters provided by FillCharBufferWithStuff
```

If I use `GetBuffer` instead of `GetBufferSetLength` it does exactly the same job.

I'd be grateful if somebody could shed a light on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The documentation isn't very clear to me and to me it sounds pretty much both functions do more or less the same thing.

Yes, pretty much. The only observable difference is that `GetBufferSetLength()` updates the stored length (and zero-terminates the buffer) before handing out the pointer:

```cpp
PXSTR GetBufferSetLength(int nLength)
{
    PXSTR pszBuffer = GetBuffer( nLength );
    SetLength( nLength );

    return( pszBuffer );
}
```

For reference, here is the `SetLength()` implementation (with state validation code omitted):

```cpp
void SetLength(int nLength)
{
    GetData()->nDataLength = nLength;
    m_pszData[nLength] = 0;
}
```

That seems like an odd thing to do. Either of the `GetBuffer()` members puts the class instance into a state where invariants may temporarily be violated. Keeping *part* of that internal state consistent doesn't seem useful, moreover, since clients can easily track that piece of information.

Functionally, `GetBuffer()` and `GetBufferSetLength()` are equivalent in producing a writable buffer of the requested size, and the choice ultimately comes down to a matter of preference. I find `GetBufferSetLength()` easier to comprehend, but `GetBuffer()` does less unnecessary work.

For what it's worth the `CSimpleStringT` implementation pretty consistently uses `GetBuffer()`, paired with `ReleaseBufferSetLength()`.

---

The above was written with the documented contract in mind that promotes the following pattern:

- Call `GetBuffer()`/`GetBufferSetLength()` to crack the insides open
- Update the innards as appropriate
- Wrap everything up with a call to `ReleaseBuffer()`/`ReleaseBufferSetLength()` re-establishing class invariants

This is easy to follow and easy to verify by inspection. That said, if you are desperate to save a function call and willing to sacrifice readability and give up following the documentation, there *is* a meaningful difference: `GetBufferSetLength()` allows you to omit the call to `ReleaseBuffer()`/`ReleaseBufferSetLength()` provided that you can guarantee to subsequently write **exactly** `nLength` characters to the buffer.

This is supported by the (current) implementation but certainly not documented and most certainly far more challenging to comprehend. I will not recommend doing this, but all things considered, this appears to be the motivation for the `GetBufferSetLength()` class member.

Answer (score 5):

If you posted the function parameters verbatim, you would see the difference.

```
GetBufferSetLength(int nLength);
GetBuffer(int nMinBufferLength);
```

And this difference is given in the descriptions.

[`GetBufferSetLength`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl-mfc-shared/reference/csimplestringt-class?view=msvc-170#getbuffersetlength)

> `nLength`
> The exact size of the `CSimpleStringT` character buffer in characters.

[`GetBuffer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl-mfc-shared/reference/csimplestringt-class?view=msvc-170#getbuffer)

> `nMinBufferLength`
> The minimum number of characters that the character buffer can hold. This value does not include space for a null terminator.

`GetBufferSetLength()` truncates or grows the buffer length if necessary to exactly match the length specified in `nLength`.

`GetBuffer()` only grows the buffer length if necessary to match the minimum length specified in `nMinBufferLength`.

Comment: Thanks. So AFAIU for my use case `GetBufferSetLength(somelength)`/`ReleaseBufferSetLength(somelength)` is best.

Comment: Still the term _nMinBufferLength_ troubles me. If I put `nMinBufferLength = N`, then I cannot modify the buffer beyond `buffer[N -1]` anyway....

Comment: In your case a possible truncation is done in `GetBufferSetLength()`, otherwise it will be done in `ReleaseBufferSetLength()`.

Comment: Actually no truncation is possible in my case because the CString is empty right before the call of GetBufferSetLength.

Comment: While this answer attracted a few *"Oh yeah, this sounds plausible!"* points I feel compelled to note that it is factually incorrect. The buffer *never* shrinks and the talk about accommodating an exactly sized buffer isn't reflected in the code implementing the functionality.

Comment: @IInspectable `The buffer never shrinks` - this contradicts to the `ReleaseBuffer()` manual: *Call this method to reallocate or free up the buffer of the string object.*.

Comment: If you find a contradiction between the documentation and the implementation, then the implementation takes precedence. Because the compiler doesn't care about the documentation. And the implementation for either of the `ReleaseBuffer()` members just calls `SetLength()`, which doesn't do anything to the buffer. You'll find the implementation of `SetLength()` in my answer.